# OSPF vs VPN site to site

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, ospf

I am new networking, I want my branch network connect to my HQ.
I don't want to lease line from ISP because my business just start small.
My question is can I use VPN or OSPF to connect from branch to HQ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a VPN Site-to-Site tunnel to accomodate your needs. That would let you connect your branch office to your HQ "securely" over the Internet ofcourse depending on which encryption you use.

Take a look at this white paper from Cisco:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk583/tk372/technologies_white_paper0900aecd8029d629_ps6635_Products_White_Paper.html

Regarding OSPF, that is a routing protocol which won't help you directly to connect the two sites. Although it can be used for routing to connect the two offices through the VPN tunnel like RIP is used in the white paper.